# Leave desicion of creating an object to constructor in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to refuse to create the object in constructor method?

My point is to set an extra parameter related to a condition.
For example:

```
public Test(Rule rule){
    if(rule == Rule.Custom)
        //DO NOT CREATE
    else{
        this.rule = rule;
    }
}

//WORK IF rule IS Custom
//I want to pass this information to user
public Test(Rule rule, string extra){
    if(rule != Rule.Custom)
        //DO NOT CREATE
    else{
        this.rule = rule;
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

Maybe i can make a factory method but i am curious about a workaround.

Comment: Throw an exception?

Comment: Maybe but my purpose is lead high level developer. I don't want to surround all the instances with try - catch.

Comment: @pilavust: So don't surround them with try-catch.  Let the program crash into the debugger and fix the number of arguments when a problem is detected..

Comment: @BenVoigt but still not user friendly.

Comment: @pilavust: This is a coding error which shouldn't ever reach the users.  Or are these parameters user-specified rather than hard coded at the call site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is to *not* throw an exception but to just not create the object, then a factory method is your only real option. That has two models:

1. Return null if conditions are not met.
2. Use the `bool TryCreate(parameters ..., out Result)` signature, where a boolean is returned to the call signifying success or failure.

Of course, the real problem with these is that the caller cannot know why the object creation failed and will need to consult some out of band information (documentation) for further info.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this pattern should be using an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.aspx).

Changing your example code to show this idea:

```
public Test(Rule rule)
{
    if (rule == Rule.Custom)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rule", "A custom rule is not allowed");
    }

    this.rule = rule;
}

public Test(Rule rule, string extra)
{
    if (rule != Rule.Custom)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rule", "Only a custom rule is allowed");
    }

    this.rule = rule;
    this.extra = extra;
}
```

Coming from a C++ background, I find myself using argument exceptions more and more where I might have used assertions in the past.

Hope this helps,

p.s.
Exceptions thrown from a constructor are perfectly acceptable...

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an exception.  That will abort the creation of the object and signals the error to the caller.

```
public Test(Rule rule){ 
  if(rule == Rule.Custom) 
    throw new WillNotCreateException();
  else{ 
    this.rule = rule; 
  } 
}
```

where `WillNotCreateException` is either your custom exception type or one of the common ones (e.g. `System.ArgumentException`)